# Bootstrap class="table" doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a simple table and am using knockout to populate the data. 
I am trying to toggle my table body using two templates. I believe that's what the boostrap does not like. Please take a look at my code and give me suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js'></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">               
  <table class="table" data-bind="visible: folks().length > 0" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse, foreach: folks}"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.addItem">New Item</button> 
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/myscript.js'></script>
<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html"> 
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
           </td>
            <td>
                 <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
            </td>            
            <td class="buttons">
                <button>Edit</button>
                <button>Delete</button>              
            </td>   
        </tr>                
    </tbody> 
</script>

<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">
<tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" ></input>                 
            </td>          
            <td>
                 <input data-bind="value: age"></input>               
            </td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <button>Done</button>
                <button>Cancel</button>
            </td>         
       </tr>
</tbody>
</script>
```

Comment: You never close your first tbody?

Comment: @g3mini: it's closed, same line.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the `tbody` tag unnecessarily in your templates. The template content gets inserted into the parent tag, which in your case is already a `tbody` element. Bootstrap is failing because the rendered table looks like

```
<table>
 ...
 <tbody>
  <tbody> 
   ...
```